# Is negative Mahalanobis distance proportional to log probability?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, determinant, mahalanobis

Is the following statement true? I was sure it was, but I was told by someone else that it is not.

$$
p(\mathbf{x}_i | y_i) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{\frac{D}{2}} |\mathbf{\Sigma}_c|^{\frac{1}{2}} } e^{ -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}_c)^\top \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}_c(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}_c) } \propto -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}_c)^\top \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}_c(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}_c)
$$

Comment: As written it is certainly false ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen what is the reason/reasons that make it fail?

Comment: In the above proportionality, you have an exponential of (neg Mahalanobis) proportional to (neg Mahalanobis) . That cannot be true, unless you have some unusual definition of proportionality!

Comment: I see, Is there an expression that would show this relationship? I was trying to say that as the LHS goes down, so does the RHS because the probability will always be lower as the Mahalanobis distance increases. I see now that the exponential violates what would be called proportional because it makes ratio of the two sides vary. So how could I express what I just said in notation?

Comment: Without getting into your formula, the conditional density $p(x_i|y_i)$ can only be derived from the joint density $p(x_i,y_i)$ or more generally $p(x,y)$, which you haven't specified. You need to tell us first what probability model we're talking about, and define your notation. For example currently there's no $y_i$ on the right side, but normally (unless there's independence) $p(x_i|y_i)$ should depend on $y_i$.